# Terraform get output of public_ip from aws_launch_configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I try to get output of public ip from aws_launch_configuration but I don't see any solution for this, so I created a data instance to filter that lauch instance to get it's public ip

```
data "aws_instance" "web_app" {
  filter {
    name   = "image-id"
    values = [var.ami_id]
  }
  depends_on = [launch_configuration.web_app]
}
```

But if I run terraform apply, it will return the error because the filter requires AMI created. So my approach won't work if I try to filter when I try to apply all of my aws instances from scratch. Is there any different way for me to do this?

Comment: Can you use different filter, for `instance_id` for example?

Comment: I tried, but same concept, that instance need to be created in order to use filter, or else querry return no result

Comment: Doesn't it just map to [describe-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)? Which off course works only on existing resources?

Comment: The problem is if I do it this way, the data filter return error which won't let me create the lauch_configuration instance when I try to run terraform apply